# Determining which height is being asked for when solving for the height of a triangle

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to understand "which height" is being requested in the following question:

In $\triangle ABC$, $\angle A = 85^{\circ}$, $c = 10cm$, and $b = 15cm$. A possible height of $\triangle ABC$ is

a) $10.0cm$
b) $8.6cm$
c) $13.8cm$
d) $12.5cm$

I think I may be missing some convention with respect to which height is being asked for... or if by triangle ABC there is a specific way that the triangle must be oriented. As it stands, I am not sure which "height" to use: there is the height from point A to the triangle's base (gives 8.6cm per my calculations), the height from point B to the triangle's base (gives 10cm), and the height from point C to the triangle's base (gives 14.9cm).

The answer in the textbook is A but no relevant explanation was given.Re: the above is provided.

TIA!

Comment: This is *indeed* ambiguous, although the altitude from vertex $A$ is less directly useful than the other two, e.g. the area of the triangle is $\tfrac12 bc \sin A$, where we can naturally interpret the base and height as $(b, c\sin A)$ or $(c, b\sin A)$.

Answer (score 1):

So u have given angle A = 85°, c = 10cm, and b = 15cm

By using cosine rule
a=$(b^{2}+c^{2}-2cbcosA)^{0.5}$
by putting the values u can find third side which is 17(approx)

so to find possible height of triangle use phythagores theorem

Pick any two sides like c,b
H =$(225-100)^{0.5}$=11.1(approx)

Now next two sides a,b
H=$(289-100)^{0.5}$= 13.7(approx)

Take a,c now
H=$(289-225)^{0.5}$=8
possible heights are these so 13.8can be the height of this traingle.
It is closest to the options thats why
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't consider this ambiguous.  It does NOT ask specifically for the length of any altitude. It asks whether any of the given numbers IS a length of an altitude.

To answer that choose ANY one of the altitudes and then see if it is one of the given numbers. If it is, answer "yes"
and you are done. If it is not, choose either one of the other two altitudes and find its length. If it is one of the given numbers answer "yes" and you are done. If it not, find the length of the third altitude. If it is one of the given numbers, answer "yes" and you are done.  If it is not, answer "no" and you are done.

Comment: Gotcha thanks. I had wondered as much; part of my difficulty was that two of the three altitudes I calculated had corresponding answers, although Antarjot above had different answers than I so I will recalculate. In any case, his answer differed from the answer in the solution manual